# Distributing AAR privately with Gradle dependencies

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, aar

I am trying to create an Android closed-source SDK package to distribute to a select number of customers.

I understand that the best way to create a distributable Android package to include source code, manifest, layout XML & other resources, etc. is to create an AAR file, and I have done this using Android Studio.

Ideally, one would then distribute the AAR via a Maven repository to allow others to use the source, along with distributing a `pom.xml` file which lists the dependencies.

However, I do not want to be forced to upload my AAR to a public (or even private) repository -- I simply want to have a way of simply distributing my AAR file via email or as a downloadable ZIP file.

The problem is that my library project has a number of dependencies (both from Maven and a local project) and AARs do not seem to themselves have any inbuilt support for listing (or even bundling) their dependencies and this needs to be handled externally (I think?).

This means that when including the AAR in another app, I end up getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` whenever I try to use any of the AAR's dependencies.

A workaround I've found (which is not ideal) is to copy the Maven dependencies into the host app's `dependencies` section of `build.gradle`. This isn't great because it's an extra step for customers to integrate the SDK, and it's not clean in terms of managing the dependency hierarchy.

This workaround also doesn't work for the project dependency I have, because that is excluded at build-time. I could probably presumably provide this dependency as source and ask my customers to add it to their project which I'm sure would work, but this just gets even messier.

So the question is: **how can one create an easily-distributable AAR file that can be dropped into another app with automatic dependency resolution without needing a repository?**

Comment: "I simply want to have a way of simply distributing my AAR file via email or as a downloadable ZIP file" -- why would your customers want this, as opposed to using an artifact repository? Please bear in mind that an artifact repository is simply a filesystem structure and can be served by a Web server.

Comment: So as you say we could host our own private repository. I guess we could even put authentication on it to prevent unauthorised access in order to control distribution. But our customers are then dependent on us to continue to host the code for them ad infinitum. Ideally we want to package our SDK as a single payload which can be delivered cleanly to customers without us having to maintain a repository for them and setup access controls.

Ultimately you're right it's no big deal to create a repository, but it does seem like there should be a way to distribute AARs & their dependencies offline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to what you are seeking is for you to distribute a Maven-style repository as a ZIP archive. This is basically what the Android Repository and Google Repository are that you get from the Android SDK. Your customers would unZIP the archive somewhere (individual workstation, common fileserver, etc.) and reference it in their module's `repositories` closure, then use normal `compile` directives. You would ship your `pom.xml` with pointers to the dependencies. Those dependencies that themselves are private would be part of the ZIP archive; those that are public would be pulled from JCenter or wherever.

(note: the only reason you don't need stuff in a `repositories` closure for the Android Repository and the Google Repository from the SDK is because the Google for Android plugin automatically adds them, more or less)

However, this will be moderately painful when you ship updates. You need to get new artifacts and `pom.xml` files into N copies of your original repository, where N is your number of active customers. Shipping a replacement repository is a possibility, but then that repository starts to grow linearly with the number of supported releases of your SDK. If you decide to yank support for older releases, you start breaking builds for anyone who has not yet moved up to a newer release, which may add to your support burden. Alternatively, you would need to work out the mechanics and instructions for distributing a repo "patchset" of sorts with just the new stuff, and hope that the customers install it properly.

Comment: It sounds like hosting this on a web server is the way to go after all!

Comment: Is there a way of bundling-in a project dependency (i.e. multi-project setup) into an AAR? I wish to include OpenCV as a dependency with my AAR, however there does not seem to be an (official) Maven distribution of OpenCV for Android, so I use it as a project dependency. What's the best way of bundling-in OpenCV to be distributed as part of my AAR?

Comment: @JonathanEllis: "Is there a way of bundling-in a project dependency (i.e. multi-project setup) into an AAR?" -- only by making it another JAR/AAR and depending upon the JAR/AAR, or by directly merging the projects (and getting rid of the dependency). "What's the best way of bundling-in OpenCV to be distributed as part of my AAR?" -- convince OpenCV to distribute an AAR. Or, create your own AAR. I wound up doing the latter for [SQLCipher for Android](https://github.com/commonsguy/sqlcipher-for-android-artifact) as I patiently await Zetitec publishing an AAR of their own.

Answer (score 0):

I've also struggled with this and [described here](http://howto-and-stuff.blogspot.com/2017/10/packaging-dependencies-into-aar-in.html) a solution that worked for me.  Basically, in order for proguard to process your dependencies with -injars directive (which places them into AAR and obfuscates), the dependencies need to be put as JARs into libs folder.  If you don't use proguard to minimize/obfuscate AAR, the dependencies will be packaged as is.